# Convert a julian date to regular date in MS Access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I need help creating a query in MS Access that converts a julian dates to MMDDYY format. An example of the dates I'm working with is: **1985037** but instead want 020685.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *DateSerial* to convert to a true *DateTime* value:

```vb
NumDate = 1985037 
TrueDate = DateSerial(NumDate / 1000, 1, NumDate Mod 1000)
```

Then, where you display it, apply a *format* to TrueDate as you like.